# In mongo if I have a bunch of IDs, is it more performant to query per ID, or by $in: IDs?

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering how `$in` works behind the scenes, and what optimizations are made. Does it loop through the database, looking for the required items, or know immediately where those are? Do indexes matter in those operations?

I'm trying to be efficient as possible, by making one query, and querying the documents I need in one go, but maybe when providing a single ID, which is guaranteed to be indexed, it's faster, and worth the multiple queries.

I guess there is a factor of how many documents we're talking about, in my case it's only a few. I assume with a lot of IDs it may worth it to just query them in one go, but maybe not. I'm not too experienced in mongo.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, It is always better to reduce network roundtrip to the database.

In your case, using $in operator is better because if you make many requests to the database for each id, you will have so many roundtrips.

when you send your query to the database, it will try to create the most efficient execution plan for your query and if there are any indices that can help to achieve a more efficient execution plan, the database will use them.

Mongo creates an index on _id filed of the document by default.